# Different between frame and header

Tags: networking, header, frame

While i study the ethernet , I cannot get the real idea of frame and header.
Sometimes I feel both are same. So i want to know weather both are same or not? if different how they are different from each other.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Ethernet frame starts with an Ethernet header, which contains destination and source MAC addresses as its first two fields.